# Existense of Lebesgue integrable function with counting measure that equals the measure of domain?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

Is it true that if $m$ is a Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ and that $\lambda$ is the counting measure on $[0,1]$, and that both defined on the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra, then there exists $h\in L^1(\lambda)$ such that $m(E)=\int_Eh\,d\lambda$?

I've been thinking about this for awhile now and have been going back and forth convincing myself it's true, then convincing myself that it's not!!! Would really appreciate if somebody settled this issue for me!! Thanks!

Comment: Is the question, does there exist some such $h$, s.t. for all $E \subseteq [0,1]$ in the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra, $m(E) = \int_E h d\lambda$? It is easy to construct some $h$ for each $E$, but constructing one $h$ for all $E$, isn't possible, by the below answer.

Comment: Ahh right, interesting. Could you show me how to construct some $h$ for each $E$?

Comment: Gave it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0=m(\{x\})=\int_{\{x\}} h d\lambda =h(x)$ so $h(x)=0$ for all $x$. This implies $m(E)=0$ for all $E$,  a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ Lebesgue measurable. Let $h = 1_{\{0\}} m(E)$ (i.e. $h(x)=0$ for all $x \neq 0$ and $h(0) = m(E)$). Then $\int h d\lambda = m(E)\int 1_{\{0\}} d\lambda = m(E) \lambda(\{0\}) = m(E)$.